# How to search in LDAP in two different distinguished names

Tags: ldap, distinguishedname

My LDAP is like these:

```
dn :uid=alice,ou=people,dc=tik,dc=test,dc=com
name:alice
email:alice@tik.test.com

dn :uid=jack,ou=people,dc=test,dc=com
name:jack
email:jack@test.com
```

How can I search with the `ldapsearch` command to get two sub DN?

I know I can use `-b "dc=test,dc=com"`, but the filter is slow because the search scope is big.

Answer (score 0):

A search in LDAP must start from a base DN. So, you can either do 2 searches, one in each sub DN, or you do a single search, but it may be slower.

This said, if your directory server is well administered and tuned, searching through a large scope isn't always slower than searching lower in the tree. It's slower if the search is not indexed (and that depends on the search filter).